# JQuery DataTable Date Order

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, sorting, datatables

I have two problems.

In my table, there is a created date column and I am soring by this date. Unfortunately it sorts as string, instead of date. (I'm using nodejs).

[image]

it had to be

21.05.2019

22.04.2109

and my code :

```
"order": [[0,"desc"],[ 1, "desc" ],[ 7, "desc" ]],
```

I've tried a plugin as well

```
"columnDefs": [                                                
                    {
                        "targets": [ 1 ],
                        "visible": true,
                        "searchable": false
                    },
                    {
                        "targets":7,
                        "type": "date-de"
                    },


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.19/js/
jquery.dataTables.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.19/sorting/date-de.js"
 type="text/javascript"></script>

$(document).ready(function() {
   jQuery.extend(jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, {
    "extract-date-pre": function(value) {
        var date = $(value, 'span')[0].innerHTML;
        date = date.split('/');
        return Date.parse(date[1] + '/' + date[0] + '/' + date[2])
    },
    "extract-date-asc": function(a, b) {
        return ((a < b) ? -1 : ((a > b) ? 1 : 0));
    },
    "extract-date-desc": function(a, b) {
        return ((a < b) ? 1 : ((a > b) ? -1 : 0));
    }
});
```

but did not work...

Comment: Please delete the question and post 2 separate questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, only one question at once, remove the select part and create a new question with it.

Your first question: In order to the datatable to order the date in the right way, you must print the date as Year-Month-Day in a hidden element.

Example, I don't know how you populate your datetable, but in plain HTML you will do something like:

```
<tr>
 <td>
   <span style="display:none">2019-05-22</span>
    22-05-2019
 </td>
</tr>
```

So when the datatable orders the column, it picks the value inside the hidden span that now can be ordered as a simple string.

Answer (score 1):

As I can see the date is in: `DD.MM.YYYY` format. To parse the date you need to split by `.` not `/`.

```
"extract-date-pre": function(value) {
    var date = $(value, 'span')[0].innerHTML;
    date = date.split('.').reverse().join('-');
    return Date.parse(date);
}
```

Comment: thank you for the answer but somehow those functions have not been invoked (I put an allert and did not show). But I made what u said and did not work as well

Comment: `console.log(date)` the after the `var date = $(value, 'span')[0].innerHTML;` and check what is being printed

Comment: nothing because this method has not been triggered.. I dont know why.. it is in the document.ready..

Comment: Post the `dataTable` initialization code. i.e `$('table').dataTable({...})` in the question.

Comment: I did like this,  dtVouchers = $('#tblVouchers').DataTable( {...}) not good idea?

Comment: No that's not it. I want to know the full initialisation code. and where are you using the `sType: "extract-date"`

Comment: I do not use stype,          {
                            "targets":7,
                            "type": "date-de"
                        },  i use like this because my date format is german format and use date-de.js